# ASP.NET Core 2.2 Integration Testing DbContext Service not registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

**Setup**

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio Professional 2017 v15.9.9
- ASP.NET Core 2.2
- EF Core 2.2
- Dapper
- xUnit 2.4.1

**Description**

I'm using the `WebApplicationFactory` from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing` package to setup my integration tests.

I've been following the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to customise the web host configuration.

The SUT uses Dapper to query from the database, so I'm not using the In-Memory provider that ships with EF Core for this particular integration test.

My code for setting up the `WebApplictionFactory` is below:

```cs
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>
    : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder
            .UseStartup<TStartup>()
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            // Create a scope to obtain a reference to the database context
            using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())    
            {
                var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var dbContext = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>(); // <-- service not found

                dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

                new MyDbContextSeed()
                    .SeedAsync(dbContext)
                    .Wait();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Issue**

The `MyDbContext` service isn't found, I understand why (I think) - because the `ServiceProvider` from my `Startup.cs` class hasn't built yet.

But the question is *How can I access the services from my Startup class here?*

For context, the Integration test looks like this:

```cs
public class MyAPITests
    : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

    public MyAPITests(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        _client = factory.CreateClient();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Get_ItemAsync_WhenIdNotFound_ReturnsNotFoundStatusCode()
    {
        // Arrange
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "api/v1/item/0");

        // Act
        var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: DbContext is Entity so you need to create a mapping of the database to c# classes.  This can be done automatically by using the Visual Studio Menu : Data : Add New Data Source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `ConfigureServices` can be used instead of `UseStartup`, not together. Second, you shouldn't create the scope and do the migration during `ConfigureServices` anyways, but rather after the Web Host is built, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2#register-the-context-with-dependency-injection):

> In older tutorials, you may see similar code in the `Configure` method
>   in Startup.cs. We recommend that you use the Configure method only to
>   set up the request pipeline. Application startup code belongs in the
>   `Main` method.

The only way to do this is not in the factory, but after the factory built it:

```
public class MyAPITests
    : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

    public MyAPITests(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        _client = factory.CreateClient();

        var host = factory.Server.Host;
        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
            var dbContext = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();

            dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

            new MyDbContextSeed()
                .SeedAsync(dbContext)
                .Wait();
        }
    }

    //...
}
```